# multiple variable assignment causing Undefined variable

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, variable-declaration, function-declaration

i've once again something i don't quite understand.
I provide you following code:

```
<?php
class Helper
{
  static function SelectDateTimeForm($type)
  {
    if($type == 'days')
    {
      $r .= "<select name='something'>";
      for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        $r .= "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
      }
      $r .= "</select>";
    }
    return $r;
  }
}
?>
```

So i wanna simply wanna return to whole select stuff inside the $r variable so that i can access it by calling the SelectDateTimeForm() function.

The Problem now is, that while i am inside the if statement (also try'd it with switch case) the $r variable seems to act somehow crazy.
When i leave the if and define the $r directly before the return $r everything seems to work.

So why can't i access or modify the $r variable inside the if? And why am i getting the Undefined variable Notice.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not because you have multiple assignment, its because you have not declared it. So declare `$r` above `if()`.

```
$r = "";
if($type == 'days'){
 .....
}
```

If `$type` is not equal to `days`, it will not enter `if()`, but you are returning `$r` which is not declared.

Comment: Yeah i checked my $type variable and it was capitalized... Thanks for giving me the bump!

Answer (score 1):

declare $r before if to be gloabl variable

```
class Helper
{
  static function SelectDateTimeForm($type)
  {
    $r = '';  
    if($type == 'days')
    {
      $r .= "<select name='something'>";
      for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        $r .= "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
      }
      $r .= "</select>";
    }
    return $r;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, i did declare it, the notice disappears but the variable still does not change inside the if statement. What am i missing?